# Regex to match Function...End Function for folding purposes?

Tags: regex, emeditor

I use [emeditor](/questions/tagged/emeditor) and I'm trying to modify the "Outline" setting so that I can collapse functions in VBS files and also so they'll show up in the outline window.  Here is the dialog:

[image]

Obviously I tried the most basic thing I could think of since I don't do Regex but it did not work.

How would I match everything between `Function` and `End Function`?

Here is an example of the XML config which allows me to collapse any elements:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward solution is a non greedy any match:

```
/Function.*?End Function/
```

Depending on your tool (I'm not familiar with emeditor), "`.`" may not match newlines! In that case use `[\s\S]` instead of the `.`. Don't forget the `?` behind the `*`:

```
/Function[\s\S]*?End Function/
```

Comment: Neither of these seem to work.  I'm sure it's something I'm misunderstanding with the program and not the regex itself though.  I have added an example of the XML config to my original post, maybe it will help?

Comment: I got it working without regex, but since this technically answers my original question I'm marking it accepted.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this regex ? `Function(.*?)End Function`

> breakdown 
>   
>   it looks for `Function` then it will group all the characters `.` 0 or more time`*` the `?` is to make it non greedy. once it sees `End Function` will close the group and let the end Function outside the group. the match is with the `Function` and `End Function` but the group is without them.

you can see a live demo at https://regex101.com/r/gY6sB8/1 the group in it is the function itself